# run parallel bash command independently to each other

Tags: bash, for-loop, parallel-processing, slurm

I have a cluster of 40 nproc where my software uses ten cores at a time. **I want to run 4 task at a time from single bash script** (job script), and whenever one completes it, start another one. The loop needs to run as per the input files (approx 600).
Each command executes in its specific folder for n times.

currently, I am using the following script

```
#! /bin/bash

for f in lib1/*.png; do
for g in lib2/*.png; do
for h in lib3/*.png; do
for i in lib4/*.png; do
        ./MySoftyware --input $f --out $f_out.png &
P1=$!
        ./MySoftyware --input $g --out $g_out.png &
P2=$!
        ./MySoftyware --input $h --out $h_out.png &
P3=$!
        ./MySoftyware --input $i --out $i_out.png &
P4=$!
wait $P1 $P2 $P3 $P4
done
done
done
done
```

The *issue is that process only starts again when all four are completed*, but I want it to execute on its next available file as soon as one is completed from the four commands.
e.g., if $f is completed before $i, it should execute the next file in $f and not wait for the completion of $i

Comment: No, this one runs a single command with max CPUs. I am restricted to 4 parallel commands independent to each other

Comment: define a function that accepts as input the sub-directory (eg, `lib1`) and processes (serially) all of the files in said sub-directory; at the top/parent level you call the function 4 times, once for each sub-directory, making sure to push the function call into the background (eg, `function lib1 &`), and then have the parent `wait` for all 4 function calls to complete

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) finds several problems with the code.  The most serious of them is that the `f_out`, `g_out`, `h_out`, and `i_out` variables are not initialized.  All `--out` arguments are just `.png`.  I suggest you provide working code that processes one file at a time and somebody might be able to help you optimize it to process 4 files at a time.  For instance, does `for f in lib1/*.png lib2/*.png lib3/*.png lib4/*.png; do ./MySoftyware --input "$f" --out "${f%.png}_out.png"; done` do what you want?  If not, why not?

Comment: GNU Parallel is a great tool for parallelising jobs, and you can use `--max-procs=4` to run at most four processes in parallel.

Comment: Also see [ProcessManagement - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement), particularly the "I want to process a bunch of files in parallel, and when one finishes, I want to start the next. And I want to make sure there are exactly 5 jobs running at a time." section.

Comment: @pjh leave $f_out.png instead consider it out.png as output.

Comment: @l0b0 will GNU Parallel work in High-performance Clusters(HPCs) ?. I am to so use to GNU Parallel

Comment: I've no idea what your particular setup is Ravi; I'd suggest looking at the documentation.